# Search by Signature

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to search for methods / functions in Visual Studio by their signature?  For example, if I wanted to find the methods (on one or more classes) that return 'string' and take an 'int' or other parameters.

If it isn't build into VS, is there an extension that anyone may know of?  Should I just bite the bullet and write my own?

Comment: Unfortunately this type of search is not built into VS

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualStudio's search with Regular Expressions:

```
(String|string) :w(.*(int|Int32).*)
```

Should find any method that returns a string and has an integer in the signature. Though the caveat is that the signature can only take up one line, and it's by no means bullet-proof to only find methods (anything that matches that pattern will ultimately be returned). But, with a little finesse you could come pretty close.

Comment: I was really only using string and integer as an example.  I don't think this would be reasonable for anything "complex".  Thanks for the idea though.